# What is a white-box implementation of a cryptographic algorithm?

Tags: implementation, white-box

What is a white-box implementation?

Does a white-box implementation have specific properties?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130717060858/http://joye.site88.net/papers/Joy08whitebox.pdf) is a nice introduction to the concept of white-box cryptography. It can be viewed as the devious cousin of code obfuscation.

In simpler words: usually, security of a cryptographic algorithm is studied in the "black-box" model: e.g., for symmetric encryption, the attacker is given access to a "device" which runs the encryption algorithm with a given key, and can submit plaintexts and ciphertexts, the goal of the attacker being to be able to decrypt a given block without submitting that exact block as ciphertext. In the "grey-box" model, the attacker also has access to some partial side-channel information; this is where [power analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_analysis) fits. In the "white-box" model, the attacker has full access to the internal state. The white-box model is meant for: "the algorithm runs as software on the attacker's own computer".

White-box cryptography is less ambitious, and correspondingly a bit less impossible, than the Holy Grail of video game vendors, namely preventing any kind of reverse engineering; WBC aims at protecting "just" cryptographic keys. WBC studies techniques by which a white-box implementation could be made, and also what security characteristics could be achieved assuming that a white-box implementation exists.

Brecht Wyseur wrote a [PhD thesis on white-box cryptography](http://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/publications/thesis-152.pdf) (there is also a downloadable [presentation](http://re-trust.dit.unitn.it/files/20061219Doc/wyseur_kul.pdf)). See also [this site](http://whiteboxcrypto.com/) (from B. Wyseur).

Comment: Am I correct that DRM and protecting proprietary software are the only valid use cases?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you are operating in some hostile environment and are defending against a "man-at-the-end" attack, WBC is applicable.

Comment: Very common use case is to protect data on mobile devices from even the user especially on open systems like Android (e.g. HCE payment)

Answer (score 5):

The goal of white-box cryptography is to build a compiler for a specific cryptographic algorithm (i.e., AES) such that given a randomly chosen key, it outputs an implementation hard-coded the key and it is hard for an adversary to extract the key. 
The key extraction is the most basic security notion for white-box cryptography, and it has been formulated as **unbreakability** in the [literature](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/523). Besides, the authors also put forward several interesting and related security notions, intuitively:

1. **one-wayness** means that it is difficult to reverse a white-box implementation.
2. **incompressibility** means that it is hard to dramatically decrease the size of the implementation.
3. **traceability** means white-box crypto could put some watermark, which is hard to remove, in order to trace the distribution of the software.

Recently, a large number of publications are discussing (indistinguishability) obfuscation, which seems to have a strong relationship with white-box crypto. Nevertheless, there is no clear link between these notions.