# Does keyless encryption exist?

Tags: hash, encoding

Does there exist an encoding/hashing/encryption scheme whereby the original string can always be derived in its entirety given the entire encoded/hashed/encrypted string, and nothing else (no key/password). But also, no portion of the original string can be derived given any portion of the encoded/hashed/encrypted string.

Basically this would be an algorithm that deterministically and reversibly jumbles up a string in such a way that the reversal algorithm requires the entire jumbled string.

Does such a thing exist? If so, what search terms should I use to learn more about it? I don't know enough about the subject to know the right words to find more information.

Comment: Unlikely. Say you have a "jumbled string" missing one character. In that case an adversary can guess / brute force the character. But maybe there is something like this where at least, say, 128 bits of information must be missing. EG you encrypt a string, then put the key at the end, and then hash the ciphertext, and XOR that with the key.

Comment: Yea that would still satisfy my practical requirements. I'm imagining strings of considerable length, and splitting the "jumbled string" into at least 3 chunks and handing them out to untrusted parties to store, so that any one party can't reconstruct any part of the original message, unless they know which chunks go together, and in what order.

Comment: Goodness, I hope I didn't just invent an encryption scheme at 2AM, I'm off to bed :P Note that this kind of thing is usually done by a secret sharing scheme.

Comment: You could use a wide-PRP with a static key. No security without the key. But any portion is useless (unless the remaining can be bruteforced. I.e. not enough bits have been lost).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you looking to do this?

Comment: What about using an arbitrary algorithm with the message itself (or a hash of the message) as the key? How exactly do you want to decrypt the message though?

Comment: Seems like a Caesar shift is a (trivial) example of this.

Comment: Yes there is. Compression. Especially very, very efficient compression. Take zip for example. Go ahead, zip a file. Then open it in a hex editor and change ONE BYTE in the middle of the file. Unzip it and you get back garbage.

Comment: @slebetman that would actually make for a good answer. Though it should be narrowed; not every compression has this property. Some lossy algorithms [like Opus](http://www.opus-codec.org/examples/) are specifically designed to be pretty robust against curruption of packets.

Comment: @slebetman Compression is not designed for that. Maybe one could design a scheme based on encryption, but proper review should be done, which is highly non-trivial. Such schemes might look robust at the first sight (like ROT13), but it does not imply it is secure. Maybe you get some bit-shift, which garbles the output, but with deeper look, you can recover most of the data. Proper secret sharing is far easier way to do the job, as there are reviewed schemes ready to be used. Also, encrypting compressed data is risky (see BREACH/BEAST), although this might not be a concern this time.

Answer (score 24):

### Clarification

> I'm wondering whether there exists an encoding/hashing/encryption scheme whereby the original string can always be derived in its entirety given the entire encoded/hashed/encrypted string, and nothing else (no key/password). But also, no portion of the original string can be derived given any portion of the encoded/hashed/encrypted string.

I am assuming that "no portion of the original string can be derived given any portion of the encoded/hashed/encrypted string" means "no portion of the original string can be derived given anything less than the entire encoded/hashed/encrypted string", otherwise the question would be self-contradictory.

### Answer

It sounds like you are looking for a permutation. A permutation is an invertible transformation on a fixed-size set of blocks. If your input is larger, the/an [All-Or-Nothing Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-or-nothing_transform) may be useful. The OAEP mentioned by @DannyNiu is an example of an AONT.

For example, many block ciphers are built by interleaving applications of a permutation with the addition of secret key material. The permutation provides diffusion, which ensures that if you modify any part of the output then attempt to invert it, you end up back at a completely different input.

If you simply strip the key addition portion from a block cipher, it should also do what you're asking. For example, [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) consists of subBytes, mixColumns, shiftRows, and addRoundKey. If you were to omit the addRoundkey operation, you would be left with a fixed permutation that provides the required avalanche effect and some degree of unpredictability. Another example of a permutation is [keccak-f](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keccak#The_block_permutation), which does the mixing for the [SHA3 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keccak).

### A key-less permutation does not provide encryption

Note that such a construction with no key is no longer providing *encryption*, as it is not possible to provide confidentiality of the message without some kind of secrecy, which is what the key provides. If anyone who has an input message can compute an output "ciphertext", or anyone who has an output "ciphertext" can invert it to the input message, then clearly confidentiality of the input cannot be achieved.

You tagged this question with "encoding", so perhaps confidentiality is not required in your use case. You would need to establish what you need this construction for and whether or not this is an issue.

Comment: This sounds *exactly* like an all-or-nothing transform.

Comment: AONT is clearly what the question is looking for. I think you should lead with it.

Comment: @otus I can do that, but I'm not so sure about the question being so clear cut, considering comments like [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57701/does-keyless-encryption-exist/57703?noredirect=1#comment126666_57705) and answers that all suggest different things, it appears that many people had different interpretations of what the asker was looking for.

Comment: Ok, maybe not "clearly", but it's the most correct. +1'd now

Answer (score 14):

Secret Sharing may be another option to consider. It allows you to take a value, break it up into arbitrarily many pieces, and possession of a subset of these pieces, not the entire set, makes reconstruction of the original value impossible. This is done by multiple means, the simplest of which is with respect to additive secret sharing. Given a secret value $x$, $m$ shares of $x$ in a group $Z_N$ may be generated by selecting $m-1$ random values and assigning them to shares $$\forall i \in \{1,\dots,m-1\},[x]_N^{P_i}\in_RZ_N $$ The final share satisfies the equation
$$[x]_N^{P_m}=(x-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}[x]_N^{P_i})\mod N$$ 
This way every share is uniform random and is secure in an information theoretic sense. Additionally, this holds up to an individual possessing any $m-1$ magnitude subset of shares. Only possession of all $m$ shares will allow the original secret to be reconstructed, and this holds without respect to assumptions or limitations on computational power. If an individual does posess all $m$ shares, reconstruction of the secret is very easy since:
$$x=(\sum_{i=1}^{m}[x]_N^{P_i})\mod N$$

Comment: In practise, I think what the OP actually needs, is to choose a random key, encrypt his text with it, and then distribute the encrypted text plus *shares* of the secret key to his N parties.

Comment: The OP should also be aware that it is possible to arrange things so the secret can be decoded if any *k* of the *N* shares are combined.  In fact, arbitrarily complex systems can be constructed (eg: at least six shares must be combined, but there must be at least two from each department, apart from audit which must be represented  by at least one share)

Comment: op can encrypt multiple times and distribute keys. Only **all** keys can decrypt the thing.

Comment: Martin Bonner, a threshold lower than the whole set of shares is not possible under additive secret sharing. It is in Shamir's scheme of course but that is not what I was discussing.

Comment: It *is* possible that [Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) may be *exactly* what the OP is really looking for, considering that the OP wrote *"I don't know enough about the subject to know the right words to use to ask the question."*

Answer (score 9):

[OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) - Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding may be what you want.

In RSA public-key encryption system, in order to prevent partial decryption, OAEP padding is used. In essence, it's a Feistel network with randomizing element.

When used alone, it can ensure no partial information can be derived from any partial information, but when the whole message is available, it's trivial.

In your case, this is no longer encryption - it's secret sharing.

[Related link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-or-nothing_transform)

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to achieve this with common algorithms would be to do the following:

1. Choose a random key (key)
2. Encrypt the data using the random key (encrData)
3. Hash the encrypted data  (encrHash)
4. Xor the key and the hash  (xorKey)
5. The result data would be the encrypted data + the Xor key (encrData+xorKey)

To reverse:

1. Split the data into encrData+xorKey
2. Hash the encrypted data (encrHash)
3. Xor the xorKey with the encrHash Because the way xor works this reverses the process above (key)
4. Decrypt the data with the key

If needed base64 the encrypted data to produce string form

With this scheme you will need the entire string to decrypt the data and can use any secure algorithm (ex AES and SHA256)

Comment: How secure would this still be if, instead of choosing a random key, we'd just split off the first 512 bits of the message as the “key”?

Comment: @leftaroundabout certainly weakens this method. That being said  this method is not secure in itself because the decryption key is already provided with the message.

Comment: leftaroundabout, If you were looking to do convergent encryption (where the same text always returns the same output) you could use the hash of the decrypted data and use that as the encryption key.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If you use the first 512 bits of the message as the key, then an adversary can decrypt any part of the message they have as long as they also have the first 512 bits, even if they're missing other parts of the message.

Comment: @AgentME those 512 bits would never be sent in plaintext, only XORed with the hash of the rest of the message.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Wait, how would the receiver decrypt the first 512 bits in the first place if their plaintext is the key? (Their ciphertext couldn't be the key to their own encryption.)

Comment: @AgentME the receiver splits up the first 512 bits (encoded key), hashes the rest of the still-encrypted message (which gives the key to the key), decodes the 512-bit key with it (which also doubles as the start of the message), and uses that to decrypt the rest of the message.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks, I can see how that could technically work now. The only problem is that if the first 512 bits of the message aren't cryptographically random, then it's a bad key. (And if it is cryptographically random, it's probably a bad message.) If someone uses that scheme on a file with a standard predictable header, then it falls apart. (And if you purposefully prefix the intended contents with a random value, then you're right back to the main answer's scheme.)
Additionally, that scheme can't be used to make a new unique and secure encryption of a previously-encrypted message.

Comment: @AgentME I don't quite see why this would be “a bad message” – in fact, anything like a standard predictable header (of more than a few bytes to indicate file type) means you're wasting bandwidth. (Not that this doesn't happen in practice...) An efficient file format maximises Shannon entropy, which also maximises security. Though it's certainly still a risk of accidentally including some boilerplate that makes it vulnerable; a cryptographic random generator is for sure a better bet.

Answer (score 1):

The "key" is secret data that are used in encryption with known "algorithm". Of course you can make keyless algorithm - get permutation, shifting stuff around, bit inversion, whatever. Employ any known strong encryption with built-in values. Mix and match all you want! However, this effectively makes algorithm itself the key. Once someone has access to your encryptor/decryptor and/or any built-in values, they don't need to know any additional data - which is ENTIRE REASON for separate key - and can decrypt whatever they want.

Incidentally that's primary and inevitable point of failure of futile attempts for DRM.

Comment: Just in case you're missing the terminology, you're talking about [white-box encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/241/13022) of AES or other block ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

## One-time pad it

Given the following conditions...

- [Alice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) has a plain-text. She wants to encrypt that.
- After encrypting it, Alice obtains several cipher-texts.
- Alice wants to give the cipher-texts to people that are not authorised to read the plain-text. None of them shall be able to decipher the cipher-text on their own.
- If all the people that have the cipher-texts give them back to Alice, Alice must be able to reconstruct the plain-text.

This is easy: **use a [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)**.

1. Alice creates a key (K<sub>1</sub>) of the same length as the plain-text.
2. Alice XORs the plain-text with the key, she gets C<sub>1</sub>.
3. Alice gives K<sub>1</sub> to Bob and C<sub>1</sub> to Carol.

Unless Bob and Carol are in cahoots, neither can reconstruct the message. When both of them give the key and cipher-text back to Alice, Alice only needs to XOR them together to get the plain-text back.

## Expanding

Alice wants better security and involves Dave and Erin. The algorithm becomes:

1. Alice creates a key (K<sub>1</sub>) of the same length as the plain-text.
2. Alice XORs the plain-text with K<sub>1</sub>, she gets C<sub>1</sub>.
3. Alice gives K<sub>1</sub> to Bob.
4. Alice repeats 1, 2 and 3, applies K<sub>2</sub> on C<sub>1</sub>, and gets C<sub>2</sub>. She gives K<sub>2</sub> to Carol.
5. Alice repeats 5, to get K<sub>3</sub> and C<sub>3</sub>. She gives K<sub>3</sub> to Dave.
6. Alice gives C<sub>3</sub> to Erin.

This can be repeated as many times as Alice likes.

There is some fragility in this as Alice needs to get the key/cipher back from **everyone** before she can get her plain-text back. But this is a problem for another post.

Comment: You have the scenario wrong.  Alice is not worried about Eve.  She *actually* want's to give bits of the encrypted message to Bob and Charlie (and possibly additional people), and for them all to be able to read the encrypted message **but only when they all combine their parts of the message**.  @webwake's answer shows how to do that.

Comment: @MartinBonner Rewritten after your comment.

Answer (score -4):

I believe this can be achieved, but of course you need to secure both of your encryption and decryption algorithms. Hide it on a very secure server with a rest endpoint where authentication is needed to be able to use the rest service. so to use the algorithm you need to send authenticated requests to your secure endpoint. Also dont forget to obfusicate your production codes.

If you are new to writing encryption algorithm you can start by learning som simple trans table encoding just to get a start. 
Your key will be mathematics and with the use of strong psuedo random number generators. So if you store all results in a database, be sure to use encryption and not pure encodings cause it will be easy to crack.

Why not try to create a random number generator too while your at it. If you can calculate the n^x decimal of sqrt(2) or Pi, or some othe irrational number you can create your own deviation to produce a strong non standard prn.

If you belive your encryption is strong enough try to give a sample of x number of pure values and the values of the encryption to see if anyone can crack them.

And lastly don’t take my word on any of this Im just a noob, with an imagination that I know something I dont, I do other stuff for a living.

Comment: If your algorithm is secret, then it's not keyless—your _algorithm_ is the key.  (This is called ‘security through obscurity’, and it's been recognized by cryptographers for over a century since [since 1883](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) to have shortcomings as a design principle.)

Comment: Nice wiki article thanks :) As I said Im a noob in this and this was a nice clearification! I think I love obscurity by nature, but I see why its not recomended for things that should not for any circumstances be comprimised.

Answer (score -5):

Let's take the simplest cipher I can think of which the key is not obvious: [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13). You replace a letter with the 13th letter after it, in the alphabet. Because there are 26 letters in the alphabet, you don't need to inverse the algorithm for decryption. Is ROT13 an example of keyless encryption, a very weak one of course? No, because 13 is your key. I don't think any algorithm that can be expressed with a computer can be keyless.

Another bizarre example of which the key is not obvious is a language. Obscure languages have been used as a form of encryption. The most famous example are the [code talkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_talker) of World War II. Navajo was an unwritten language at that time and the only way to encrypt a message was using your language skills and your mouth. You decrypted a message using your ears, your language skills, and pen and paper. So is this form of encryption keyless? To answer that question, we have to know if this algorithm can be expressed by a computer. There is no way for a computer to translate English to Navajo right now, but there are services that can translate English to Chinese and vice versa. If we trained a language model that could automatically translate English to Navajo using a computer, that model would be your key.

So this answer doesn't ultimatively exclude any form of keyless encryption might exist. I just had a look at some encryption topics not covered by RFC or NIST and I don't think it's possible for keyless encryption to exist.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what the OP is trying to do.